# Ruby on Rails -- undo mark_for_destruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, destroy

In my rails app the child records get [marked_for_destruction](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/mark_for_destruction) I want to undo that action and unmark them. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

`child.reload if child.marked_for_destruction?`

From [ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-reload):

> **`reload`**`(options = nil)`
>
> Reloads the attributes of the object as usual and clears marked_for_destruction flag.